# ngMessagesInclude doen't work in ngMessages directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Includes:

```
angular/angular.min.js
angular-route/angular-route.min.js
angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js
```

---

This is my module.

```
var axipay = angular.module('axipay', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngMessagesInclude',
    'axipay.registration',
])
```

---

I used it like this.

```
<div ng-messages="form_register.phone.$error">
      <div ng-messages-include="error-messages.html"></div>
</div>
```

This gets an error when loaded.

> Failed to instantiate module ngMessagesInclude due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMessagesInclude' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

This working correctly without 'ngMessagesInclude'.

### Ref:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessagesInclude

Comment: Did you include messages.js in your HTML. `<script src="angular-messages.js">`

Comment: yes. That's why it's working without ngMessagesInclude

Answer (score 0):

There is no module named **ngMessagesInclude**. Once you define the ngMessages dependency, you can access the **ng-messages-include** directive. So, remove the ngMessagesInclude dependency.

```
var axipay = angular.module('axipay', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMessages',
    'axipay.registration',
])
```

Comment: Ooopzz .. What a huge mistake. Let me try. tx

Comment: Now it's complaining this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd?p0=document